# Mouse click handle other event

Tags: javascript, jquery, cursor, mouse

I have an `div(#magenta)` which follows my mouse trough the entire screen, which is linked via jquery. Now, since javascript doesn't allow me to move the mouse, i can move the div.
Here's what i want to do, when the user clicks, the anchor tag below the `#magenta` was to act.

So example:

Li action: `alert(a)` -> 'real' mouse is here
Li action: `alert(b)` -> `#magenta` is hovering here
The user clicks and javascript alerts b.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

And the JSfiddle to demonstrate:
http://jsfiddle.net/5Mhh7/

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking... do you think you could post some code? or better yet a jsfiddle?

Comment: Was just working on it, it's hard to explain!

Comment: Why explain when you can show what you have... http://jsfiddle.net/ Basically, you need to listen for click events and call trigger()

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5Mhh7/

Comment: It sounds like you want: If the magenta box is above the second `li` element and you click the first `li` element, the page will alert something... Right now I see that no matter where the magenta box is, when the first `li` element is clicked, the box moves down 30 pixels. is this correct?